# Searching for an element within lists of lists without MAPCAR

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

I attempted a question of making a program that replaces all instances of an element `A` within a list `L` with `T` and unlike elements with `NIL`. The bet is to not use `mapcar`.

Here is what I did earlier. I am storing all `T` and `NIL` in a new list `POS` then returning `POS`.

```
(defun SRC (A L) 
  (defun _SRC (A L POS) 
    (COND ((NOT (EQUAL (CAR L) NIL))
           (_SRC A (CDR L) (APPEND POS (LIST (EQUAL A (CAR L)))))) 
          ((EQUAL (CAR L) NIL)
           (APPEND POS (LIST (EQUAL A NIL))))
          (T POS)))
  (CDR (_SRC A L (LIST NIL))))
```

Current behaviour:
The program is working nicely, except when searching for `NIL` itself, but that special case is not of concern here.

Few example runs of my code:-

```
   (SRC 'g '(a g g o t g))
> (nil t t nil nil t)
```

When searching for `NIL` in a list:-

```
   (SRC nil '(t a t nil nil))
> (nil nil nil t)
```

In this singular case our program ends on finding the first NIL in the list, for other searches, the program works fine. So I tried adding the ability of **searching within lists of lists.**

My updated code for searching within lists of lists without `mapcar`:

```
(defun SRC (A L) 
 (defun _SRC (A L POS) 
   (COND ((LISTP (CAR L))
          (APPEND POS (LIST (SRC A (CAR L))))) 
         ((NOT (EQUAL (CAR L) NIL)) 
          (_SRC A (CDR L) (APPEND POS (LIST (EQUAL A (CAR L)))))) 
         ((EQUAL (CAR L) NIL) 
          (APPEND POS (LIST (EQUAL A NIL))))
         (T POS)))
 (CDR (_SRC A L (LIST NIL))))
```

Now, the output that I expect from this code is as follows:

```
  (SRC 'e '(a b e c (e g e) h t e))
> (nil nil t nil (t nil t) nil nil t)
```

Instead my code runs forever, causing stack overflow, and I could not figure out anything with callstacks or backtracking.

Answer (score 7):

**Unreadable code due to lack of indentation.**

Your code is unreadable, because your code is not indented.

```
(defun SRC (A L) 
(defun _SRC (A L POS) 
(COND ((NOT (EQUAL (CAR L) NIL)) (_SRC A (CDR L) (APPEND POS (LIST (EQUAL A (CAR L)))))) 
      ((EQUAL (CAR L) NIL) (APPEND POS (LIST (EQUAL A NIL))))
      (T POS)))
(CDR (_SRC A L (LIST NIL))))
```

Let's indent your code.

```
(defun SRC (A L) 
  (defun _SRC (A L POS) 
    (COND ((NOT (EQUAL (CAR L) NIL))
           (_SRC A (CDR L) (APPEND POS (LIST (EQUAL A (CAR L)))))) 
          ((EQUAL (CAR L) NIL)
           (APPEND POS (LIST (EQUAL A NIL))))
          (T POS)))
  (CDR (_SRC A L (LIST NIL))))
```

**Style and basic mistakes**

Basic mistakes or programming style problems:

- `defun` should not be nested. `defun` is not for defining local functions. `defun` should only be used for global functions. Use `flet` or `labels` for local functions.
- use `first` and `rest` instead of `car` and `cdr`
- use speaking variables
- use lowercase

**Don't start with nested functions**

I would start without nested functions.

```
(defun _src (element list pos) 
  (cond ((not (equal (first list) nil))
         (_src a (rest list) (append pos (list (equal element (car list)))))) 
        ((equal (first list) nil)
         (append pos (list (equal element nil))))
        (t pos)))

(defun src (element list)
  (cdr (_src element list (list nil))))
```

**Simplify recursion**

But then you can greatly simplify it using the usual recursive pattern:

```
(defun mark% (element list result) 
  (if (null list)                            
      result                                  ; empty list -> return result
    (mark% element                            ; mark the rest of the list
           (rest list)                        
           (cons (equal element (first list)) ; equal for the first element?
                 result))))

(defun mark (element list)
  "return a list with boolean values if element is found in the list"
  (reverse (mark% element list nil)))         : needs to reverse the result
```

**Note**

Generally don't program recursive functions like that, since Lisp actually already offers `MAP` and `MAPCAR` - those provide the mapping functionality in one place and it is not needed to bake the recursive mapping into each function of your own.

Preferably use higher level iteration facilities like LOOP:

```
CL-USER 13 > (loop for e in '(a b a b)
                   collect (equal 'a e))
(T NIL T NIL)
```

**Nested lists**

You can adapt the above function to nested lists by adding a case testing for the first element being a list and then doing something in that case...

```
(defun mark% (element list result) 
  (cond ((null list)
         result)
        ((consp (first list))
         (mark% element
                (rest list)                        
                (cons (mark element (first list))
                      result)))
        (t
         (mark% element
                (rest list)                        
                (cons (equal element (first list))
                      result)))))
```

**Debugging**

Use `trace` and/or `step` to see what your code is doing.

Comment: While this is valuable, but I also need to know where my code went wrong and why it overflowed the stack..

Comment: @Subham: I think you need to improve your code first to make it readable. It's usually a waste of time to debug unreadable&unformatted code. Then I would trace the functions to see what they are doing. See the macro CL:TRACE .

Comment: there.. I indented it correctly, I hope it is correct.

Comment: @SubhamBurnwal: better to get rid of the nested `DEFUN`. `DEFUN` is only used for global functions. Trying to use it for local functions is a mistake and does not lead to the desired effect.. If you have global functions in the first place, it's also easier to trace them - though some implementations can trace local functions.

Comment: The nested DEFUN is a foolishness on my part. In all my lisp programs I have never nested it. The exceptional behaviour you see here is because I read a program somewhere online where DEFUN had been nested and I thought oh it might be the usual way one should do it although my textbook mentions nothing of this. **I will correct it in the question** but I hope I wont get scolded for editing after recieving an answer. :(